# Push/pull multi row columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know if my approach makes sense, however, I need to achieve a layout like this picture:

[image: Bootstrap layout]

Now, I'm writing just a single `<div class="row"></div>` and representing each area with a column inside of it, e.g. `<div class="col-sm-4></div>`.

Without the yellow area, this works fine:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">green</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">red</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">blue</div>
</div>
```

How can I add the yellow area? There's no col-pull-16 or things like that, what's the way to go?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't be done without using Flexbox or jQuery or using css to hide and show and duplicating the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check the `Flexbox` and sepcially the `order` property (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Can you please provide a simple example, just to give me an idea?

Comment: There's a sample on the link provided and plenty of examples by googling.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. Hope it helps.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        RED
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        BLUE
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        Green
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                Red
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
                BLUE
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/68n54p47/2/

Comment: `col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4` is highly redundant and equivalent to simply `col-sm-4`!

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to duplicate areas and the yellow box is not the body. It's a column.